# How to convert dataframe column names from strings into arguments suitable for (qplot, ggplot2)?

Tags: string, r, arguments, ggplot2, dataframe

I want to write a function that takes a dataframe, and graphs all the columns in that dataframe as histograms.

For a dataframe whose column names I know beforehand, I can write

```
qplot(colname1, data=df, geom='histogram')
qplot(colname2, data=df, geom='histogram')
...
```

but I want to do this generically, so that I can use the name of the column as a string `"colname1"`.

In other words, how to write

```
plot_histogram_of_column <- function(df, colname) {
    # qplot(colname, data=df, geom='histogram') won't work
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `ggplot` and `aes_string`. Something like this:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes_string(x = colname)) + geom_histogram()
```

`aes_string` was written precisely for this purpose.

Comment: As documented here: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/aes.html

Note, though, that, as far as I can tell, NO page of the ggplot2 documentation site links to this, so the only way to find it is by knowing to search for it.

Comment: @Maxy-B The built-in docs (`?aes`) are much improved in version 0.9.0, and contain a link to the help page for `aes_string`. I can't recall if this was the case in 8.9.0.

Comment: Yes. I just independently solved my own problem related to this. This function is incredibly obscure and hard to discover, yet important. Surely one of the first things you would want to parameterize when plotting a large dataset is the identity of the y-series, yet the examples don't emphasisize this. (I edited your title for clarity)

Comment: The idiomatic way is now : `ggplot(data = df, aes(x = !!ensym(colname))) + geom_histogram()`