# Selecting data frame columns to plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a big table of data with ~150 columns. I need to make a series of histograms out of about 1/3rd of them. Rather than putting 50 lines of the same plot command in my script, I want to loop over a list telling me which columns to use. Here is a test dataset to illustrate:

```
d <- data.frame(c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5)),
                sample(c(1:10), 10, replace=TRUE),     
                sample(c(1:10), 10, replace=TRUE),     
                sample(c(1:10), 10, replace=TRUE),     
                sample(c(1:10), 10, replace=TRUE),     
                sample(c(1:10), 10, replace=TRUE))

colnames(d) <- c("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6" )


ggplot(data=d, aes(col2, fill= col1)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5)
```

So, rather than writing this a 50 times and replacing the `aes()` values, I really want to do something more like this...

```
cols_to_plot <- c("col2","col4","col6")

for (i in length(cols_to_plot)) {
  ggplot(data=d, aes(cols_to_plot[i], fill= col1)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5)

}
```

But of course, this doesn't work... Is there a way to do this kind of thing?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert dataframe column names from strings into arguments suitable for (qplot, ggplot2)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570855/how-to-convert-dataframe-column-names-from-strings-into-arguments-suitable-for)

Comment: Doh! It is a dup, I missed that one in my search...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you'd be better off if you melted your data. Try this:

```
library(reshape2)
d2 <- melt(d, id='col1')
ggplot(d2, aes(value, fill=col1)) + geom_density(alpha=.5) + facet_wrap(~variable)
```

Or, if you wanted to do what you originally wanted, use `aes_string`, like:

```
ggplot(data=d, aes_string(cols_to_plot[i], fill='col1')) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5)
```

Comment: I am still not sure how to plot only certain columns without using a loop, it should be possible with ggplot, no?

Answer (score 8):

Since version 3.0.0 of ggplot2, the `aes_string()` function has been *soft deprecated*, with the focus now to use `aes()`.

The trick now is to use the `.data` object to refer to the data object supplied to `ggplot()`, which here is `d`.

Using this, we recover the behviour prior to version 3.0.0 without the soft deprecation wraning:

```r
d <- data.frame(c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5)),
                sample(c(1:10), 10, replace=TRUE),     
                sample(c(1:10), 10, replace=TRUE),     
                sample(c(1:10), 10, replace=TRUE),     
                sample(c(1:10), 10, replace=TRUE),     
                sample(c(1:10), 10, replace=TRUE))

colnames(d) <- c("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6" )

cols_to_plot <- c("col2","col4","col6")

for (i in seq_along(cols_to_plot)) {
  print(ggplot(data = d,
               aes(x = .data[[cols_to_plot[i]]], fill= .data[["col1"]])) +
    geom_density(alpha = 0.5))
}
```

---

##### Original answer using `aes_string()`

There is an alternative to `aes()`; `aes_string()`. With this you can pass in strings for the aesthetic mappings. Note you have to quote `col1` here in `fill = "col1"`. Also note that in a `for()` loop you need to explicitly `print()` a **ggplot** object in order for the plot to be drawn on the current device.

```
d <- data.frame(c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5)),
                sample(c(1:10), 10, replace=TRUE),     
                sample(c(1:10), 10, replace=TRUE),     
                sample(c(1:10), 10, replace=TRUE),     
                sample(c(1:10), 10, replace=TRUE),     
                sample(c(1:10), 10, replace=TRUE))

colnames(d) <- c("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6" )

cols_to_plot <- c("col2","col4","col6")

for (i in seq_along(cols_to_plot)) {
  print(ggplot(data=d, aes_string(x = cols_to_plot[i], fill= "col1")) +
    geom_density(alpha = 0.5))
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this would have had me on a wild goose chase for sure!

Comment: For the record: "`aes_string()` was deprecated in ggplot2 3.0.0. Please use tidy evaluation ideoms [sic] with `aes()`".

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `aes_string`

```
cols_to_plot <- c("col2","col4","col6")

for (i in cols_to_plot) {
  ggplot(data=d, aes_string(i, fill= 'col1')) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5)

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`lapply()` could be used here in place of a `for` loop with `aes_string()`.

```
cols_to_plot <- c("col2","col4","col6")
lapply(cols_to_plot,function(i){
  ggplot(data=d, aes_string(x=i, fill= 'col1')) + 
    geom_density(alpha = 0.5)
} )
```