# How to plot density curves for each column in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

I have a data frame `w` like this:

```
>head(w,3)
         V1        V2         V3        V4 V5        V6         V7        V8        V9       V10 V11        V12        V13        V14
1 0.2446884 0.3173719 0.74258410 0.0000000  0 0.0000000 0.01962759 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5995647   0 0.30201691 0.03109935 0.16897571
2 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.08592243 0.2254971  0 0.7381867 0.11936323 0.2076167 0.0000000 1.0587742   0 0.50226734 0.51295661 0.01298853
3 8.4293893 4.9985040 2.22526463 0.0000000  0 3.6600283 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.2573714 0.8069288   0 0.05074886 0.00000000 0.59403855
         V15       V16      V17       V18      V19       V20       V21      V22         V23        V24       V25       V26       V27
1 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.1250837 0.000000 0.5468143 0.3503245 0.000000 0.183144204 0.23026538 6.9868429 1.5774150 0.0000000
2 0.01732732 0.8064441 0.000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.015123385 0.07580794 0.6160713 0.7452335 0.0740328
3 2.66846151 0.0000000 1.453987 0.0000000 1.875298 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.893363 0.004249061 0.00000000 1.6185897 0.0000000 0.7792773
        V28 V29     V30       V31        V32        V33       V34       V35 V36        V37        V38       V39        V40    refseq
1 0.5543028   0 0.00000 0.0000000 0.08293075 0.18261450 0.3211127 0.2765295   0 0.04230929 0.05017316 0.3340662 0.00000000 NM_000014
2 0.0000000   0 0.00000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.03531411 0.0000000 0.4143325   0 0.14894716 0.58056304 0.3310173 0.09162460 NM_000015
3 0.8047882   0 0.88308 0.7207709 0.01574767 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.1183736   0 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.3529881 0.03720155 NM_000016

dim(w)
[1] 37126    41
```

I tried to plot the density curve of each column(except the last column) in one page.  It seems that ggplot2 can do this.

I tried this according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570855/how-to-convert-dataframe-column-names-from-strings-into-arguments-suitable-for):

```
ggplot(data=w[,-41], aes_string(x=colnames)) + geom_density()
```

But it doesn't work by complaining like this:

```
Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

And I'm not sure how to convert the format of this dataframe to the one ggplot2 accepts. Or is there other way to do this job in R?

Comment: You need to `melt()` your data into long format, the question here shows you how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479822/plotting-4-curves-in-a-single-plot-with-3-y-axes-in-r/5481187#5481187

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use "melt" from the "reshape" package (you could also use the base reshape function, but it's a more complicated call).

```
require (reshape)
require (ggplot2)
long = melt(w, id.vars= "refseq")

ggplot(long, aes (value)) +
    geom_density(color = variable)

# or maybe you wanted separate plots on the same page?

ggplot(long, aes (value)) +
    geom_density() +
    facet_wrap(~variable)
```

There are lots of other ways to plot this in ggplot: see
http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_histogram.html for examples.

Comment: what exactly is the "refseq" which you are using as id here?

Comment: @kira It's the 41st column in OP's data set, the only one that's not numbers (it looks to be gene accession numbers from the NCBI Reference Sequence Database http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/refseq/, but it would be a pretty good guess as an id column anyway)

Answer (score 9):

`ggplot` needs your data in a long format, like so:

```
variable  value
1 V1  0.24468840
2 V1  0.00000000
3 V1  8.42938930
4 V2  0.31737190
```

Once it's melted into a long data frame, you can group all the density plots by variable. In the snippet below, `ggplot` uses the `w.plot` data frame for plotting (which doesn't need to omit the final `refseq` variable). You can modify it to use facets, different colors, fills, etc.

```
w <- as.data.frame(cbind(
  c(0.2446884, 0.0000000, 8.4293893), 
  c(0.3173719, 0.0000000, 4.9985040), 
  c(0.74258410, 0.08592243, 2.22526463)))
w$refseq <- c("NM_000014", "NM_000015", "NM_000016")

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
w.plot <- melt(w) 

p <- ggplot(aes(x=value, colour=variable), data=w.plot)
p + geom_density()
```

[image: Example plot]

Comment: I have a similar issue. In my case I have 1000 columns and no header-names (so in R they're called 'X1', 'X2', etc). If I do `melt(df)` I get an error `Using X404, X755, X974 as id variables
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names`. How should I interpret that?

Comment: Ah! I use `read_table2` to load in the data - very fast solution. But it turns the data in a `tibble`, rather than a `data.frame`. So if I convert it to a `data.frame` it works!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using the `plot` function and a little loop

Call your plot

```
plot(density(df[,1]), type = "n")
```

then run this to add the lines

```
n = dim(df)[2]-1
for(i in 1:n){
lines(density(c(df[,i])))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make a 8 x 5 grid of the density plots with multiple lines on each plot coloured by the variable refseq...

```r
library(tidyverse)

w_density <- w[,1:40]  # columns you want densities for
w_density$refseq <- w$refseq  # maybe you have a variable to group by

w_density %>%
    pivot_longer(!refseq, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = value, colour = refseq)) +
    geom_density(show.legend = TRUE) + 
    facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free", ncol = 5) + 
    ggtitle("Title goes here")
```

If the grid is not the right size and you're using Rmd then you can play with the chunk sizes...

````r
```{r, fig.height=20, fig.width=11}
````