# Pass variable columns with optional facets in a function via ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to figure out how to create multiple ggplots with one function, to avoid tedious copying and pasting. I do not want to have to change argument names in the function when I want to use different columns in the same data.frame. There may be completely different approach to this problem, but I am including two attempts that *almost* worked but still fall short of what I want. 
Thanks!

**Edit**
I would also like the function to add a facet depending on on argument, such as groupBy="brand", for example. I think aes_string along side of https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-October/213946.html may get me there. I included my facet request as part of my question, because aes_string alone falls short of my goal of being able to facet as part of the plot function. I added brand to the dataset, just to share what I could not find by searching online today.

```
library(ggplot2)

### sample data ###
n=25
dataTest = data.frame(
  xVar=sample(1:3, n, replace=TRUE), 
  yVar = rnorm(n, 5, 2), 
  zVar=rnorm(n, 5, .5),
  brand=letters[1:5])

### a first attempt ###
  ### works, but forces me to create a new function whenever column names need to change
  my_plot =function(data) {ggplot(data=data, aes(x=xVar, y=yVar))+geom_bar(stat="identity")}
  do.call("my_plot", list(data=dataTest))
  ### wish for something like this... but this does not work
  my_plot = function(data) {ggplot(data=data, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_bar(stat="identity")}
  do.call("my_plot", list(data=dataTest, x=xVar, y=yVar))
  do.call("my_plot", list(data=dataTest, x=xVar, y=zVar))

### a second attempt, does not work ###
my.plot = function(x, y, data)
{
  arguments <- as.list(match.call())
  data = eval(arguments$data, envir=data)
  x = eval(arguments$x, envir=data)
  y = eval(arguments$y, envir=data)
  p=ggplot(data=data, aes(x, y))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
  return(p)
}
my.plot(x=xVar, y=yVar, data=dataTest)
```

Comment: Have you considered using `aes_string`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert dataframe column names from strings into arguments suitable for (qplot, ggplot2)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570855/how-to-convert-dataframe-column-names-from-strings-into-arguments-suitable-for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `aes_string` will allow you to pass character strings into your ggplot2 function, allowing you to programmatically change it more easily:

```
my.plot = function(x, y, data)
{
p=ggplot(data, aes_string(x=x, y=y))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
print(p)
}

my.plot(x="xVar", y="yVar", data=dataTest)
```

[image: yvar]

```
my.plot(x="xVar", y="zVar", data=dataTest)
```

[image: zvar]

Comment: I added a variation which works for facets, if you have any feedback related to it please let me know :)

Answer (score 2):

What about using `%+%` to update the plots instead?

Example:

```
library(ggplot2)

### sample data ###
n=25
dataTest = data.frame(
  xVar=sample(1:3, n, replace=TRUE), 
  yVar = rnorm(n, 5, 2), 
  zVar=rnorm(n, 5, .5) )

p1 <- ggplot(data = dataTest, aes(x = xVar, y = yVar)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

aes2 <- aes(x = xVar, y = zVar)

p2 <- p1 %+% aes2
```

p1:

[image]

p2:

[image]

EDIT

or as @sebastian-c mentioned, `aes_string`

```
plots <- function(x, y, data = dataTest) {
  p1 <- ggplot(data = data, aes_string(x = x, y = y)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")

  p1
}

plots('xVar','yVar')

plots('xVar','zVar')
```

EDIT 2: beat me to the punch :o

Comment: If only `y` is replaced, `p1 + aes(y = zVar)` is enough.

Comment: @Henrik I am replacing x and y, and my main goal is more complicated, using fill as a group variable via facet_wrap. I did not realize you could do this though, probably handy in some other situations though :)

Comment: so you are trying to pass a string onto `facet_wrap`? I think  you would definitely want to use `%+%` then

Comment: There are reasons that I did not explain in my original post why that wont work for my specific case... I guess I tried to make my question too simple. I am using this outline to make jittered outliers on boxplots using facets optionally in the function to cover all possibilities. So I want to remove the geom_points() layer  and replace it with a new layer every time I make a new graph. If I wasn't doing that too, your solution would work well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using @sebastian-c's answer and other sources, I have a function that I think will work and I wanted to share it. I think I see @Henrik's solution, but it seems like more typing, as I have 4 groups, 4 'x' categories, and a third category related to time (year, quarters, months).

```
library(ggplot2)

### sample data ###
n=25
dataTest = data.frame(
  xVar=sample(1:3, n, replace=TRUE), 
  yVar = rnorm(n, 5, 2), 
  zVar=rnorm(n, 5, .5),
  brand=letters[1:5])

### function
my.plot = function(x, y, data, group=NULL)
{
  p=ggplot(data, aes_string(x=x, y=y, fill=group))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
  # make a facet if group is not null
  if(length(group)>0) {
    facets = facet_wrap(formula(paste("~", group)))
    p = p + facets
  }
  return(p)
}
```